# Weird CSS Transition Flickering on hover

Tags: css, hover, css-transitions, microsoft-edge

I recently encountered an 'Issue' in the Edge Browser using the following code leading to a weird hover transitioning behavior on links.

**Take a look yourself:**

- [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/js4hpoye/4/)
- [The App I'm working on ('Test' Link)](https://slooob.com)

**HTML:**

```
<a><h1>Test</h1></a>
```

**SCSS:**

```
* {
  transition: all .15s ease-in;
}
a {
  color: inherit;
  &:hover {
    color: blue;
  }
}
h1 {
  color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you did not follow color assigning. The weird behavior could be associated with to this improper use.  A:hover must be placed after the `A:link` and `A:visited` rules, since otherwise the cascading rules will hide the 'color' property of the A:hover rule. Similarly, because A:active is placed after A:hover, the active color (lime) will apply when the user both activates and hovers over the A element.

```
link {color: blue;}    
visited {color: purple;}   
hover {color: red;}      
active {color: yellow;}
```

Comment: Try adjusting the width of the hover. Some times, browsers, without default width, make this behavior.                                                     a:visited a:hover{
  width: 17em;
  background: #B2CDE0;